# Confusion about the tensor product of Hilbert spaces and tensor product of smooth vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

Denote by $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,  \mathbb{R}^n)$ be the collection of of vector fields $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to  \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}  \lvert f_i(x) \rvert^2dx < \infty
\end{equation}
where each $f_i : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is the $i^{th}$ component of $f$.

Then, $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,  \mathbb{R}^n)$ is a Hilbert space. Moreover, the $2-$fold tensor product of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,  \mathbb{R}^n)$ is another Hilbert space generated by the following set
\begin{equation}
\{ \{f_i(x) g_j(y) \} \mid f, g \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,  \mathbb{R}^n)\}
\end{equation}
with respect to the inner product
\begin{equation}
\Bigl \langle \{f_i(x) g_j(y) \} , \{h_i(x) w_j(y) \} \Bigr \rangle:= \sum_{i,j=1}^n \Bigl[\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_i(x) h_i(x) dx\Bigr]\Bigl[\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g_j(y) w_j(y) dy\Bigr].
\end{equation}

However, in the context of differential geometry, I see that given a smooth manifold $M$ and  two smooth vector fields $X,Y$ on it, the tensor produt $X \otimes Y$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
X \otimes Y : M \to TM \otimes TM \text{  where } (X \otimes Y)_p:=X_p \otimes X_p \in T_pM \otimes T_pM \text{ for each } p \in M.
\end{equation}

This causes extreme confusion for me...For the Hilbert space, $f$ and $g$ have "different arguments" when forming a tensor product: $f\otimes g= \{ f_i(x) g_j(y) \}$.

But, for differential geometry, $X \otimes Y$ is still evaluated at "a common point": $(X\otimes Y)_p$

Could anyone please clarify??

Comment: They are two distinct objects that unfortunately share the same name. That's all.

Comment: Oh.....thank you for your lucid clarification...